# Handle CPU exceptions outside of KVM

Tags: c, kvm

I would like to trap and handle CPU exceptions outside of KVM. How can I achieve this?

```
    /* KVM_EXIT_EXCEPTION */
    struct {
        __u32 exception;
        __u32 error_code;
    } ex;

    Unused.
```

From the documentation. This exit status is apparently not implemented.
Yet, to handle an exception afaik you would have to exit the guest first anyway.

I'm not going to write an IDT in the guest, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved this by handling the exceptions unprivileged (in usermode), and simply trap into the hypervisor using any method of doing such, like writing to a trapping MMIO address. In my case the guest is always unprivileged and can't modify its own pagetables, so the host will be setting everything up before entering the guest.

This works completely fine, however backtraces will need to be handled remotely.